# How to disable Copilot using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, regedit

I am new to scripting/coding. My work has tasked me to get rid of or disable copilot from showing up and being utilized till we get all the greenlight from our state IT people to use it. This is what I have so far and I am running into errors that I can't seem to see.

```
-    # Create a new instance of the Windows Script Shell object
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"

    # Modify registry key for Copilot eligibility
$RegPath1 = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Copilot\BingChat"
$objShell.RegWrite("$RegPath1\IsUserEligible", "0", "REG_DWORD")

Start-Sleep -10

    # Modify registry key to show Copilot button in Windows Explorer
$RegPath2 = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced"
$objShell.RegWrite("$RegPath2\ShowCopilotButton", "1", "REG_DWORD")
```

It seems to work but I am getting an error message that I can't get PS to show. I have tried modifying the regedit but that option isn't available on my end for some reason. I have changed the start sleep to 10 instead of milliseconds 3000.

Comment: 1. look around for the correct way to format code in posts, so to maximize readability(anhd thus chances somebody will be able to help you). 2. please edit your post with the actual error message, because the devil is in the details of the error messages.

Comment: Could you give some context to your question (by editing it)? What is your actual objective? In what context is Copilot being used? Could you just uninstall it?

Comment: Hey thanks to the both of you for the comments.  For the context of this we can't just uninstall Copilot. I currently work for a state agency and we aren't authorized to use AI  on our computers for security purposes. O365 now comes with Copilot and we are just trying to disable it through a GPO to the masses till our sister agency gives us the greenlight on using it.   To sirtao, I am sorry for the formatting error, I have never used this platform before and know there are a ton of ppl that now scripting and coding way better. I will try and reformat it and PS wouldn't stay open to get errors